# Nginx 1.8 Configuration Problems

Tags: windows, networking, nginx, php, configuration

Here is the problem : 
(I'm new to NGinx, read about it, but didn't find my working solution yet.)

I'm on a Windows system.

My projects file system is located there :

```
E:/www/
```

here is a project folder I will try to reach later in this example :

```
E:/www/projectTest
```

I have an apache server running fine. I'd like to set up a Nginx server in parallel, this is why i configured my nginx using another port (see config file below).

Nginx files are there :

```
E:/nginx/
```

I copied a php there :

```
E:/nginx/php/
```

Here is my example 'index.php' I place in my current folders to test my php and nginx config :

```
<?php
    echo "THIS IS A TEST";
?>
```

Here is my nginx.conf file (I removed commented lines) :

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8111;
        server_name  localhost;
        root E:/nginx/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        charset utf-8;  
        location / {
            alias E:/www/;
        }

        location /projectTest/ {
            alias E:/www/projectTest/;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root ../www;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/conf/$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like everything is running fine,
Meaning that if I wan to reach my 'localhost:8111/index.php' or 'localhost:8111/projectTest/index.php', I get the 'index.php' i placed there and the text "THIS IS A TEST" appears on my screen.

BUT :

I noticed that, when I open Firebug to test my page, I always receive this as error message (EVEN IF I GET MY PAGE) :

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8111/
    //Same error when I call index.php in url : 
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8111/index.php
    //Same error when I call my projectTest folder :
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8111/projectTest/
    //Same error when I call my index.php in projectTest url : 
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8111/projectTest/index.php
```

Here is how I start Nginx in command line :

```
E:\nginx>nginx.exe
E:\nginx\php>php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c e:/nginx/php/php.ini
```

in php.ini :

```
doc_root = "E:/www"
extension_dir = "E:/nginx/php/ext"
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

There must be something wrong in my nginx configuration,
I'm coming from Apache so I'm really confused with this .conf file,
I read many things about it but I'm still not comfortable at all with the "root" or "alias" values, and with the fast-cgi php thing...

Thanks for reading/help/advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your configuration:

1. You specify `root` on the server level, and then specify `alias` in `location` blocks. This isn't wrong in itself, but causes confusion easily.

If all your project files are under `E:/www`, I would use these remove both the `location` block with `alias` blocks, and would set up only `root E:/www` inside the `server` block.

2. You specify `root` directive inside your `.php` processing block. That won't work.

If you don't have any special requirements for your web server, I would use this setup for PHP:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

With this setup, nginx will look up your files to be served from `E:/www` directory, and it will pass any PHP files to PHP-FPM for execution.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But for php : I don't have any /etc/ folder. My fastcgi_params is in the /nginx/php folder somewhere. And about fastcgi_param $document_root$fastcgi_script_name, what does $document_root mean then?

Comment: Your config seems to have solved my problem. Need some more explanations to really understand your php block if you can :)

Comment: Ah sorry, I just copied my Linux nginx configuration here. `$document_root` means just the path of the current document root specified in another location block. `$fastcgi_script_name` means then the PHP script filename in the path.

Comment: Ok, thanks for these details. The reason why I try to set up a Nginx server is to use it for ws:// do you have some knowledge in this? may we chat (if you have some time)?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with ws://